# Looking for a database server on an embedded system

Tags: windows, database, sql, server

So I'm looking for a database server which needs to run with the following requirements:

1. Run on [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP).
2. Log in via [TCP/IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).
3. [Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication#Factors_and_identity).
4. Expose custom [stored procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure).

It will be running on an embedded CPU and will primarily facilitate data-logging.

The data itself will be quite simple. Only a few tables at most, but may potentially reach ~200GB in size. There will only be one write pipeline, and multiple (but few) readers.

Some of the options I've considered:

- [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) - slightly worried about the cost/licensing, as we're an OEM.
- [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) - file-based (so no native tcp/ip access), no stored procedures.
- [PostgeSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) - might be too big/complex.

Any insights/suggestions welcome!

Comment: if MySQL is not too large/complex -- MariaDB? -- the free fork of MySQL, GNU GPL lic

Comment: Logging in over a network and an embedded system mean two totally different things. Please explain.

Comment: @BasilBourque Effectively this is for the computer embedded in an OEM unit. Labelling a system as _embedded_ doesn't preclude it from having the capability of network access.

Comment: We've each been using a different meaning of *embedded*. Apparently you meant [embedded system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) while I meant a database engine built-in as a part of the app rather than running separately in its own process (or machine) as a server. I suggest editing your Question to clarify. You may get better answers if you describe the characteristics and constraints of your embedded system hardware and OS. For example, Postgres most certainly is *not* built to be embedded, while the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) is (optionally)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @BasilBourque. I'll investigate a bit more into the definitions and modfiy the question accordingly.

Comment: I meant Postgres, for example, is *not* built to be embedded within the app (my context above), but does indeed run on embedded computer hardware system like a Raspberry Pi (apparently your context above) in its own process alongside your app or other apps running in other processes.

Comment: @flamey could you please post MariaDB as a answer (because it is :) and explain why it meets each of the OP's three criteria?

Comment: This Question is still too vague to produce a spot-on Answer. Describe your embedded hardware platform. Are talking about a Raspberry Pi or Beagle Bone?  What kind of CPU? How much RAM? What kind and size of storage? And perhaps briefly explain why Windows XP, as that OS being end-of-life makes it your biggest challenge to finding a solution.